# Black screen after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS to 20.04.1 LTS from system updater, but I faced unknown problem and it didn’t complete the upgrade.
Then after restart my computer, the system show the ubuntu background then can’t complete to open, I just see a black screen with dash symbol.

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> it will appear the second picture attached, I don’t know what write in login field?

[image: login at boot]

How can I repair my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was eventually able to solve it like this:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to bring up a TTY console
2. Log in. I had to try this several times before the system would accept my username and password.
3. Update the system:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   sudo apt upgrade -y
   ```
4. Reboot:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

Voila!

Comment: This solution worked for me after upgrading 18.04 to 20.04 within a Hyper-V Gen 1 setup and fixing the kernel panic issue via 'sudo update-initramfs -u -k 5.4.0-169-generic' and then 'sudo update-grub'.  Note that under Hyper-V, had to use Ctrl+Alt+F3 to get to the root prompt.  Thanks for the black screen fix!

Answer (score 1):

Since no one knows what happened during your "update" I'd suggest you try to save your data (using a live usb stick to access your hard drive) an then install 20.04 newly. I've never had the guts to do this - too may obstacles and too many people complaining about it.

Since that update did not overwrite your data, you'll have a good chance to retrieve whatever is missing before setting up your new system.

Comment: I saved my data in an external hard drive before doing upgrade, but I don’t want to reinstall Ubuntu newly if I must have a DVD or flash usb to boot from it. 

Something else, there is virtualbox program in my computer, it will be deleted after upgrade if successful?

Comment: If you don't want to make a new update - good luck. You'll learn a lot by finding out which packages are broken and how to fix them. If you setup a new Ubuntu your VB will be gone - you'll have to set it up again, since a new install will **erase everything from your disk**

Comment: I will be proud if I can learn and fixed missing packages, than do an easier solution that is setting up a new system. My important data saved externally, ok not important to loos and deleting VB. How I learn and fix packages?

Comment: I like your attitude. Well, your problem comes in two stages. First of all you need to enter into grub - the bootloader. Obviously that does not even happen. The first thing you have to check is how your grub setup is configured. Does it point to the initramfs in the boot directory? So first step is to get grub running. You could take your live USB stick and reinstall grub. Make sure the correct partion is setup. If grub shows there are more options to analyze to errors. I'll stay tuned ;-)

Comment: I must wait until tomorrow to buy an USB =| then what to do is: install copy of system to open as testing and install grub, true?Something else, can I use tty to solve problem? But it says my login incorrect, l’m sure it was correct and I don’t have (num lock keys). It is acceptable capital letters?

Comment: I can access BOIS, it’s helpful to use?

Comment: Download the Ubuntu 20.04 ISO file. I usually put in on the stick with dd. If you don't know how, check this forum. I've answered that question serveral times already. Then do not start the default install mode, but take the "repair " mode. There are plenty of answered questions of how to install grub with a live USB stick. You will learn ....

Answer (score 0):

if you can get to a login terminal
enter your `username` at the first prompt then you will be asked for your normal `password`
If this is successful you should be able to do a `sudo apt-get update`
or a `dpkg --configure -a` if it tells you to

Comment: I could login, it said: “login incorrect”. But I am sure it is correct!